# Can ubuntu be compromised?

Tags: windows, webcam, remote, malware

My main reason for switching over here from Windows was because with the release of Windows 10, the VP of Microsoft wrote in the ToS (Yes, I read this with my very own eyes while installing it) that they collect a bunch of data, including software data, phone numbers, email addresses, residential addresses, and webcam data for "marketing purposes"

I was wondering if such a policy existed with Ubuntu, can my webcam be jacked in Ubuntu? 
I've used a bunch of commercial software for Windows that let me access my webcam remotely and even record while the LED light was off.

I'm not paranoid, I'm just trying to retain the little of what rights I have left.

Comment: *webcam data* probably means that Microsoft get the model name, not that they record videos without the consent of the user.

Comment: "Being compromised" usually means being infected with virus, trojans, or accessed illegally. If they collect information with your consent (especially since you are one of the few who actually read ToS), that doesn't count as being compromised.

Comment: If you're worried that the built-in webcam might record things without you noticing, cover or tape something over the lens while you're not using it. It's an easy enough “fix” that I often see even amongst non-paranoid hackers.

Comment: They collected that data in the dvelopment release and strictly wrote *this should **NOT** be used as a every day computer*. For that explicit reason. You should probably wait until they release the final version before you make up your mind...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Ubuntu can be compromised, as any other OS, trojans, phishing, social engineering, password cracking, browser exploits - all work in Ubuntu.

There is no policy of collecting the same amount of data as Windows 10 does (apparently, for developing purposes, which doesn't make it compromised in any way), and yet, there are Amazon adds in the dash - the feature some did call spyware. There is also a popularity tool in APT, that sends the list of installed packages.

PS: Not sure what rights you have in mind. Privacy is a choice, most definitely in this case.

Comment: Both the dash Amazon search and `popularity-contest` can be disabled after installation by the way.

Comment: +1 for "PS: Not sure what rights you have in mind. Privacy is a choice, most definitely in this case."

Answer (score 4):

Yes, any Software and any OS **can** be compromised. Ubuntu is no exception.

[This is the data](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy) which Ubuntu will collect.

You might want to disable the online search. [image: Change 'when searching in the Dash, include online search results' to 'OFF']

As for protecting Ubuntu from threats, the following post covers the Ubuntu security aspect pretty good, so I'm linking it here: [Security and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384526/security-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

And if need be, it might useful to lay it thick and emphasize the importance of the 7th rule taken from Ubuntu's Basic Security page, already linked above by [MadMike](https://askubuntu.com/users/75166/madmike):

> *7.  most important of all: use your common sense. **The biggest security threat is generally found between keyboard and chair**.*

to which I would add that this is the case for any OS, and in fact for any human endeavor, where security is of relevance. Be sloppy with anything Linux or otherwise, and you'll soon be a sloppy toast.